# Communication between two ViewModels with same Model and two views

Tags: c#, design-patterns, observer-pattern, mediator

I have a C# Application with two different views. Each view has an own ViewModel. The ViewModels access the same Model. The Views need the data from the same Model in a different format. The ViewModels handle the formatting and validation.

Both ViewModels should be able to communicate with each other in some way. For example if ViewModel1 updates something in the Model ViewModel2 should also update his View. The ViewModels don't have to know each other, they should just get synced when one side changes something.

I found some old posts aout the Mediator pattern. Is this still the way to go? I think the Observer pattern would not work here. The only alternative I could think of was to create a Interface on both ViewModels which let them talk to each other.

Comment: Mediator pattern is relevant here. Use `Prism`s `EventAggregator` to post and respond to state change events between ViewModels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think what your looking for is Message-passing system for your View Models.if you what them to be loosely coupled you can use events to implement one by yourself.
also there is [Event Aggregator](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/event-aggregator.html) class in prism library that do the same.some classes subscribe and some publish their messages.

Comment: What is the benefit to use this instead of the mediator pattern? With an event based system both ViewModels have to know each other?

Comment: i dont know much about mediator pattern.but as i understand it looks like the same with one draw back.the mediator it self have to know about the other objects.so that it can handle the messages.but in prism event aggregator u dont really need to do any thing.just subscribe to an event and publish the message.@J.Doe

Answer (score 1):

The pattern most relevant to this would be MVC. If you are using .Net Core, you can read up on it on the [Microsoft Docs online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

The Controller would be able to return a View Model that has the updated values. You could also have just 1 View model that is used by both views that you have.

Comment: I am not using .Net Core.For every update I would receive a complete new ViewModel? Doesn't that hurt performance?